# Rolling Ball Image Background Subtraction

Tags: image-processing

I am currently doing particle detection on some images and I wanted to do an Image Background Subtraction similar to what is available on ImageJ so as to even out the background tone.

ImageJ uses a Rolling Ball algorithm which I believe is a type of Top-hat transform using a ball as a structuring element.

I currently have to do the background subtraction in ImageJ and then import the file to Mathematica to do the rest of the particle detection.

Could anyone help me write a rolling ball background subtraction algorithm in Mathematica, or does anyone know another way that I can flatten out/even out the background tone of my image?

This is my first question, and I'm not well versed in image processing, so I'd be happy to provide any other information that might be useful if I can. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `TopHatTransform` command? The second argument (the kernel) can be specified to be any shape you wish (like a disk).

Comment: Please add as much info, code and sample data to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own filter, using `DiskMatrix` embedded into a zero matrix the size of the image, and then apply your filter with the resulting mask, iteratively "rolling" the disk insert. Probably not very efficient compared to using such an algorithm in an image-processing program where it's coded/compiled at low level.

Nonetheless, there are *tons* of fairly efficient means in *MMA* to make "particles" stand out in an image, I offer this rudimentary example:

```
    (* make a smeared background *)
    background = MedianFilter[RandomImage[1.5, {200, 200}], 10];

    (* populate it randomly with twenty one-pixel "particles" *)
    data = ImageData[background];
    (data[[# /. List -> Sequence]] = 100) & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 200}, {20, 2}];
    particles = Image[data]

    (* do a median filter on result, subtract from original *)
    ImageSubtract[particles, MedianFilter[particles, 10]]

    (* result via TopHat (as suggesed by bill s *)
    TopHatTransform[particles, DiskMatrix[1, 7]]
```

Original:

[image]

Filtered:

[image]

TopHat:

[image]

Comment: Rohan: Appreciate the accept much, but almost always wise to hold off a day or so: you never know what clever answers may emerge, and who knows, someone may read it that has implemented the exact algorithm you're interested in...